# Form waits for second submission to push through first submission

Tags: php

I'm new to development and I'm trying to build a contact form using php that pulls the info from a contact form. My contact form works and collects the data as needed, but when I click submit the first time I don't receive the information to my inbox. When I refresh the page, complete the form a second time and click submit once more, **I receive both submissions to my inbox at the same time.** It's as if the first submission waits to be pushed through by the second submission. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to stop it?

I've seen a lot of posts regarding submissions happening twice but my issue is the first doesn't come through until the second is sent.

Here is my PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $radio = $_POST['time'];

    $mailTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: " . $mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an enquiry from: " . $name .
            "\n\n Phone Number: " . $phone .
            "\n\n Address: " . $address .
            "\n\n Message: " . $body .
            "\n\n Time to call: " . $radio;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: index-contact.php?submission");
}
```

I'm testing on localhost8888 using MAMP Pro.

Here is HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method="post" id="form">

    <label for="name">Full Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name" required>

    <label for="email">Email Address:</label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address" required>

    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number" required></input>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Please enter a subject" required></input>

    <label for="address">Postcode:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Please enter your postcode"></input><br>

    <label for="body">Comments:</label><br>
    <textarea name="body" placeholder="Please enter your message"></textarea>

    <input type="radio" id="morning" name="time" value="morning">Morning</input>
    <input type="radio" id="afternoon" name="time" value="afternoon">Afternoon</input>
    <input type="radio" id="anytime" name="time" value="anytime">Anytime</input>

    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Send Message</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using other mail servers to send your email from them?

Comment: @EhsanT no, I built the form and within the mamp pro settings set the postfix outgoing domain settings to gmail.com and it worked as it should. I then came back to it a week later and tested again to make sure it was still running as it should but this time i ran in to the issue of it waiting for a second submission. Can you recommend any good servers to test on? thanks

Comment: Gmail is a reliable mail server to use. Have you tried to remove the redirect line `header("Location: index-contact.php?submission");` and add a normal `echo` instead for the debugging purpose to see if you see the debug text every time or you get it every other time as well?

Comment: I removed the location header and the echo, I decided it was a server issue and not something in my code. I noticed when i looked at the path of the emails that had been delayed compared to the first ones id sent a week prior they were coming from different Message ID's the first from @)mbp-lan.com and the latter ones from @)gmail.mailer.com. The latter emails were also failing DMARC and SPF as they couldn't be verified, essentially I was sending an email to myself while posing as myself indirectly through the form. Google couldn't verify that it was legit and i think was quarantining emails.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you update the page, you will be resending the POST.
As this is a contact form, i suggest installing Google reCaptcha. Thus, it will be necessary to resolve the captcha and this will not happen.

There are other ways. One of them would be to store user data in a database and only authorize a sending by IP or session at a certain time.

Or you can just work with direct session and prevent this from happening, using the function in your code:

```
function prevent_multi_submit($type = "post", $excl = "contact") {
    $string = "";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        // this test is to exclude a single variable, f.e. a captcha value
        if ($key != $excl) {
            $string .= $val;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['last'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['last'] === md5($string)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['last'] = md5($string);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['last'] = md5($string);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your code will look like this:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit']) and prevent_multi_submit()) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $radio = $_POST['time'];

    $mailTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: " . $mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an enquiry from: " . $name .
            "\n\n Phone Number: " . $phone .
            "\n\n Address: " . $address .
            "\n\n Message: " . $body .
            "\n\n Time to call: " . $radio;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: index-contact.php?submission");
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Or, add a simple parameter to the URL that redirects, so that a second POST is not authorized:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) and $_GET["sent"] != "ok") {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $radio = $_POST['time'];

    $mailTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: " . $mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an enquiry from: " . $name .
            "\n\n Phone Number: " . $phone .
            "\n\n Address: " . $address .
            "\n\n Message: " . $body .
            "\n\n Time to call: " . $radio;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: index-contact.php?sent=ok");
}
```

Read more about HTTP GET variables at [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Maybe i've misunderstood you, I tried both suggestions. I first added the prevent_multi function to the top of the php file then added session start() and added prevent_multi to the if function but that didn't work. I also tried using the $_GET method, but that also didn't work. Both ways I still had to submit the form twice to receive the emails. When I used the GET method the error log read 'undefined index: sent..' do i need to add something to the html like how the POST is targeting the submit button? Thank you, I appreciate the help

Comment: @RossKS change $_GET["sent"] to @$_GET ["sent"]. The @ is for ignoring errors. It is showing when there is no value in $_GET["sent"]